# Docker container running but can't view in browser

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, docker

I'm new with **Docker** and i'm trying to run **ruby** app inside a docker.
So i created a ruby app that work and run fine, I also created a image and a docker that when i run and build them it's running just fine.
After I running the docker it's shown like it's running without problems, i get an IP from `docker inspect` and the port shown at `docker ps -a`  as 3000.

when i open the IP:port at the browser I can't see nothing.

**here is my docker file:**

```
> FROM ruby:latest 
> 
> # Set the working directory to /app WORKDIR /app
> 
> # Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app ADD . /app
> 
> RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' |
> debconf-set-selections RUN apt-get update \
>     && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=Noninteractive   apt-get install -y \
>         sqlite3 \
>         thin \
>         nodejs \
>         apt-utils \
>     && bundle install 
> # --no-install-recommends apt-utils sudo
> 
> 
> #RUN sudo -H cp config/initializers/rack_attack.rb config/initializers/rack_attack.rb
> 
> # Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
> # RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 
> EXPOSE 3000
> 
> CMD ["bundle",  "exec", "rails", "server"]
```

**Edit:**

I tried also with '**Expose 3000**' and also run with '-p' flag.
When i run 'docker ps -a' the **ports** are: '**0.0.0.0:32768->3000/tcp**'.
For 'docker inspect' i get the **IP**: '172.17.0.2'

but when i go to 'http://172.17.0.2:3000/' in the browser i see nothing.

**NEW EDIT**

> I discover that the docker is running as tcp6 (IPv6), how can i
>   configure it to be tcp? .

Comment: If you want that to be accessible outside the container you need an `EXPOSE`; see the reference https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#usage

Comment: What's the URL you are trying to acess in the browser?

Comment: @JulioHM i edited the question. i'm trying to access this URL: 'http://172.17.0.2:3000/'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my problem.
the solution was to run the docker as **production** and not as **development**.

in **Dockerfile**, instead of:

```
CMD ["bundle",  "exec", "rails", "server"]
```

I changed to:

```
CMD ["bundle",  "exec", "rails", "server", "-e", "production"]
```

and that **solved** my problem

Comment: do you know why this was the case?

Answer (score 5):

Add this line in your dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 3000
```

Also, if you want this app to be accessible from your host, run with the `-p` flag.

See "[General form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#general-form)" for the `run` documentation.

Comment: As per your update it seems port 32768 is exposed. Try 172.17.0.2:32768